# javascript taking # marker literally

Tags: javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite

I have some code on some of my links

```
<a class="nav_bu" onclick="switchType('all'); return false;" href="#">
```

when I click on them, I get fowarded to mydomain.com/# (404 error..).

How can I get the function activated, rather then the `href` link.

P.S. I have mod_rewrite running, is this screwing things up?
Here are the rules that effect the root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^home/$ home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^inbox/$ inbox/inbox.php [L]
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you have an error in the `switchType('all')` function. That is why the browser does not get to `return false;` and uses the default action to redirect you to `href`.

Comment: Agree with this. I never had problems with the #.

Comment: Agreed, the shown code is just fine, so there has to be an error in the function. Show Javascript errors: In IE enable "Display a notification...", in Firefox open the error console.

Answer (score 3):

use button instead of link

Comment: Agreed. Buttons should be buttons, links should be links.

Comment: There is a point to that... However there is still an error in the functon that is called so it doesn't fix the root of the problem.

Comment: right, but there is no more problem with '#', and you don't spend hours to find a bug in mod_rewrite rules:)

Comment: @Guffa: by the way, your answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133581/is-23-148-855-308-184-500-a-magic-number-or-sheer-chance is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you state, based on your tags, that you are using jQuery. Why would you be using inline javascript listeners then?

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav_bu').click(function() {
        switchType($(this).attr('rel'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

If this is your HTML:

```
<a class="nav_bu" rel="all" href="#">Blah Blah</a>
```

But, yeah... like people are saying, you probably have a problem with your `switchType` function. Run the site in Firefox with Firebug installed and it should tell your right where you problem is.